# How do I solve the ReferenceError in my API calls from my UI?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have done a microsoft tutorial called Web API with Javascript
I now have a UI made with Javascript and HTML which looks like this: [image: Finished UI]

How do I use the UI? I keep getting a Reference Error. Is there a specific syntax I am supposed to follow when I add and edit something via APIs?

Comment: The warnings in the console show that the browser couldn't load the JavaScript file (site.js). Therefore, none of the functions you're trying to call is defined, hence the errors. Go to https://localhost:44347/js/site.js and check if you can see the script.

Comment: @Chris G I can't. It's empty :/

Comment: Double-check that you have a folder called `js` in your `wwwroot` folder, and that the `js` folder contains a file called `site.js` which contains all the code from the tutorial.

Comment: Check your code with the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/samples)

Comment: @Chris G Thanks it worked. The tutorial did not tell us to make a folder named js. It just said to put the site.js file into the wwwroot directory.

Comment: Ah, true, I didn't even think to check the path against the instructions. I left feedback for the tutorial's author about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please copy and paste error messages into your question. I would normally copy and paste the error message in my answer, but I don't want to type it all out :)

The errors (red) mean that you're trying to use JavaScript that is not defined yet. The warnings (yellow) are the reason why.

The second warning says that it could not load the JavaScript. That explains the errors. The first warning *might* be the reason why. It's saying that the MIME type is empty, when it should be `application/javascript`.

But you said in the comments that the `site.js` file is empty when you try to access it directly. Did you save all the JavaScript in step 4 of that tutorial to `site.js`?

And what are you using as a web server? IIS Express?

Comment: Thanks. Yes am using IIS Express. The problem was that I had not added a folder called js to the wwwroot directory.

Comment: @CodingStudent Right. That will do it.